# AdroidStudio: trying to play a mp4 but it keeps displaying as a text file

Tags: java, file, android-studio, mp4, android-videoview

I'm not sure whats going on. I'm just tying to run a simple one min video through android studio and for some reason when the file gets called it just craps out.

Here is my mainActivity I dont see any problems with it

```
package com.example.videodemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.introVid);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Here is what I'm seeing happen to my mp4 file when trying to run the app

[image]

I'm not sure whats going on I even restarted androidStudio after invalidating caches and still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the (must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9) goes for the video resource as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Uri instead of Path

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.introVid));  // try this code
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: I tried Uri and got the same result. I'm not sure whats going on it's like the program doesn't see it as a video file